# Drawing a line between two points android & google maps

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout, layout, maps

I am working in a google maps and I want to draw a line between two points I used the following code from a user question in this site but it didn't work with me I have a force close when I remove this function in the inner class the application works

but I need it because I have to draw lines

The code I used is the following:

```
    class MyOverlay extends com.google.android.maps.Overlay {
    GeoPoint [] geoPointsArray ;
// constructor 
public MyOverlay(){

    }   

@Override 
public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapv, boolean shadow){
    super.draw(canvas, mapv, shadow);

    Paint   mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setDither(true);
    mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(2);

    GeoPoint gP1 = new GeoPoint(19240000,-99120000);
    GeoPoint gP2 = new GeoPoint(37423157, -122085008);

    Point p1 = new Point();
    Point p2 = new Point();
    Path path = new Path();

    projection.toPixels(gP1, p1);
    projection.toPixels(gP2, p2);

    path.moveTo(p2.x, p2.y);
    path.lineTo(p1.x,p1.y);

    canvas.drawPath(path, mPaint);
}
```

}// end of the inner class

I really need help, when I just add this thing I got a force close :S

Comment: Please see my answer and if you have any queries then tell me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this to add one or more points to your Overlay and fill them with RED color.

```
public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) 
    {
        super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);

        Paint mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        mPaint.setStyle(Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
        mPaint.setAlpha(9);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(2);

        Path path = new Path();

        Projection projection = mapView.getProjection();

        for(int j = 0; j < geoArrayist.size(); j++) 
        {
            Iterator<GeoPoint> it = geoArrayist.iterator();
            while(it.hasNext()) 
            {
                GeoPoint arrayListGeoPoint = it.next();

                Point currentScreenPoint = new Point();
                projection.toPixels(arrayListGeoPoint, currentScreenPoint);

                if(j == 0)
                    path.moveTo(currentScreenPoint.x, currentScreenPoint.y); 
                else
                    path.lineTo(currentScreenPoint.x, currentScreenPoint.y);
            }                 
        }
        // old_geopoint = new_geopoint;
        canvas.drawPath(path, mPaint);
    }
```

geoArrayList is a List of Geopoints.

Comment: I liked your solution but still there is a problem when ever I add this function the application stops working and I get a black screen in my mobile... its annoying because I am 90 % sure that the code is correct

Comment: Make sure to test it on a device..and make sure that u have included correct api key in your application. Best thing would be to re-generate the api key for your mapView and use the new key. This happens sometimes, and it has happened to me too, and just entering a new api key made it work. I dont know where you are exactly going wrong..but this might be one of the reasons

Answer (score 0):

Use below stack-overflow answer for drawing route between two points on Google map, it may help you.

[Draw Route Path on Google Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11428650/draw-a-line-in-a-route-map/11428745#11428745)

Comment: I used ur solution and I got error in the following line of code, where the toPixel is not working                                   for (int i = 0; i < mPoints.size(); i++) {
            Point point = new Point();
            mv.getProjection().toPixels(mPoints.get(i), point);
            x2 = point.x;
            y2 = point.y;