# KML file from google as location indicator

Tags: android, google-earth, google-maps-api-2

my application gets geopoints between  two locations using KML file from google maps by URL
(which worked successfully for a long time)

**https://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&hl=en&saddr=vishakapatnam&daddr=hyderabad&ie=UTF8&om=0&output=kml**

but now instead of downloading KML file it is directly showing google maps page and also it is not working inside application as main source of my app is KML file and as there is no 
KML file to parse,
 the parser is returning a NULL pointer exception

is there any other location source which provides KML files?
or any other possible solution to my problem?

Answer (score 1):

Google change here location service from kml to xml or json format , so it is better use google location json service.

check the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11428650/draw-a-line-in-a-route-map/11428745#11428745)

Thanks